# How to delete options by click on cross symbol (image) or any api to delete options in select list

Tags: jquery, select

this is my code and I want to put delete feature in each option so that user can delete options dynamically

Client
        Resource
        Site
        Options
        Meals

Comment: <select id="selection">
        <option>Client</option>
        <option>Resource</option>
        <option>Site</option>
        <option>Options</option>
        <option>Meals</option>
    </select>

Comment: Perhaps this will help you http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/